# Options to expand storage

Tags: raid, storage, esata

I was browsing through external storage enclosures and I read that some enclosures are not supported by the eSATA port on the motherboard if it does not have port multiplier functionality. I found that my M2N-SLI Deluxe's eSATA port does not have the functionality and want to know what my options are with adding storage. Is it possible to get a [SATA expansion card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816322010) or similar with a [storage enclosure](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816111177) and still be able to use my motherboard's hardware RAID functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up purchasing an [eSATA card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816322010) with port multiplier functionality and an [external enclosure](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816111177).

Answer (score 0):

First what is your goal?  How much storage do you need?  How many and what size hard drives do you have?  If you want 9tb of RAID 6 the answer is very different than 2tb.  I have an external promise case that can hold 16 hard drives linked to an adaptec 5805.